# Box2D Debugger Not Working With Starling

Tags: actionscript-3, debugging, box2d, starling-framework

I'm using Box2D with The latest version of Starling, i'm trying to use the Box2D debugger, but nothing is working so far, this is what i tried, i added a Flash layer on top of the stage3D layer so i'll be able to use the Flash Sprite, i'm running my app on the web.

The Main Class :

```
    public function BallFriction()
    {
        this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onReady, false, 0, true);
    }

    private function onReady(event : Event) : void
    {
        this.removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onReady);


        var stats:Stats = new Stats();
        stats.y = 500;
        stats.x = 50;
        this.addChild(stats);

        stage.color = 0x333333;
        stage.stage3Ds[0].addEventListener(Event.CONTEXT3D_CREATE, onContextCreated);

        oStarling = new Starling(Game, stage);
        //          akaStarling = new Starling(BoxWorld, stage);
        oStarling.antiAliasing = 1;
        oStarling.start();


    }

    private function onContextCreated(e:Event):void{
        //debug mode
        debugSprite=new Sprite();
        addChild(debugSprite);

        (BallFriction.oStarling.stage.getChildAt(0) as Game).debugDraw(BallFriction.debugSprite);
    }
```

The Game World :

```
  public function Game() 
    {
        super();

        // Create a b2World with gravity 9.8 towards y axis. 
        world = new b2World(new b2Vec2(0, 9.8), true);

        floor(400,590,800,20);
        theBall = ball(100,400,ballWidth/2,Texture.fromBitmap(new Ball()));
        // I also set the velocity of the ball
        theBall.SetLinearVelocity(new b2Vec2(8, -8));

        // Listen enterframe event and update world for each enter frame
        this.addEventListener(EnterFrameEvent.ENTER_FRAME, updateWorld);
        this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage);
    }

    private function onAddedToStage():void
    {
        this.removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage);

        //(BallFriction.oStarling.stage.getChildAt(0) as Game).debugDraw(BallFriction.debugSprite);

    }

 private function updateWorld(e:EnterFrameEvent):void
    {
        world.Step(timestep, 10, 10);
        world.DrawDebugData()
        world.ClearForces();
    }

    public function debugDraw(debugSprite:flash.display.Sprite):void{
        var debugDraw:b2DebugDraw = new b2DebugDraw();
        debugDraw.SetSprite(Starling.current.nativeOverlay);
        debugDraw.SetDrawScale(30);
        debugDraw.SetLineThickness( 1.0);
        debugDraw.SetAlpha(1);
        debugDraw.SetFillAlpha(0.4);
        debugDraw.SetFlags(b2DebugDraw.e_shapeBit);
        world.SetDebugDraw(debugDraw);
    }
```

Comment: Way too complicated to troubleshoot site alone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't look like you've added any flags to your debug draw logic using `b2DebugDraw.AppendFlag()` or `b2DebugDraw.SetFlags()`; the flags tell the debug draw what kind of information it needs to draw on the screen. Most likely you will want to use the `b2DebugDraw.e_shapeBit` flag.

It also doesn't look like you've defined the draw scale using `b2Debug.SetDrawScale()`, though I am not certain without being able to check it right now whether that is absolutely necessary.

Checking out the [`Debug`](https://github.com/MartyWallace/Sentinel/blob/master/src/sentinel/gameplay/physics/Debug.as) class in my game framework might help you out - it handles this exact problem.

Comment: .. I edited the debug function (edited my post) and it worked, the weird thing is i already tried that solution before and nothing happened that's why i had to go with a simpler solution, i don't what changed except for turning my computer off in the night, Thank You, also if you have any other examples with Starling & Box2D that'll be great, i can't find much out there :).

Answer (score 1):

You have to call `world.DrawDebugData()` every time you call `step()`

Comment: .. I edited my Question and added the update method, even with using the  world.DrawDebugData() nothing appears.